# How to add a US Zip code mask on angular material input accepting 00000-0000 or 0000

Tags: regex, angular, angular-material, masking

I'm looking for a regex or a mask that allows me validate an angular material input using both formats (00000-0000 or 00000). 
My code allows me to put only a zip code like this 12345-6789 but not this one 12345. I'm using ngx-mask. and working with Angular 7.

```
 <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput name="zipCode" placeholder="Zip Code" [(ngModel)]="site.zipcode" mask= '00000-0000'>                                               
 </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: For a regex, try: `\d{5}-\d{4}|\d{5}` or just `\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?`. If you want to be sure you don't partial match, add `^` to the beginning and `$` to the end of either of those patterns, then it will only match if the whole string is exactly that pattern, like so: `^\d{5}-\d{4}|\d{5}$` or `^\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?$`

Comment: @Delisaysusebaldaji Kindly check I have Updated answer let me know if there will be any issue

Answer (score 1):

```
Validators.pattern('^[0-9]{2,5}(:|\\-)?[0-9]{3,4}')
```

in html

```
pattern="^[0-9]{2,5}(:|\-)?[0-9]{3,4}"
```

Comment: Please elaborate on this with a summary and description text for people that don't understand just the code.

Answer (score 0):

try this

**UPDATED ANSWER**

First we need to install package from https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-text-mask2

using `npm i angular2-text-mask --save`

And than import it in root module file e.g App.module.ts

Like this

```
import { TextMaskModule } from 'angular2-text-mask';
```

import it in `imports[TextMaskModule]` Array of `@NgModule({})` decorators

and in component.ts file

```
myModel: any;
abcd = [/\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, "-", /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/];
```

in template file

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput [textMask]="{mask: abcd}" [(ngModel)]="myModel" placeholder="Type a value">
  </mat-form-field>
```

I hope this will work

Comment: Just a note to readers that this method requires the importing of a module from a third party source that is unlicensed and the last published version was 3 years ago. People that are working for companies might be concerned about this.

Answer (score 0):

use this regex :

```
    zipcode = '^[0-9]{5}(?:-[0-9]{4})?$',
```

TS File

```
Validators.pattern(RegexEnum.zipcode)
```

**it will help you to validate the US zip code**.

I hope it will work